# I want make custom line html chart

Tags: html, charts

I need a chart code like photo. Can anyone help me?
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPZoK.jpg)

Comment: html , css , js . I searched but none of them seemed to look like the picture

Comment: Then you need to specify what you means with "like this".

Comment: Exactly like the photo. No grid, rounded corners, two charts and ...

Comment: Then yes: this is the description of almost every graph with a little of css.
I'll do not suggest you some names, but search on google and almost every graph in first page is good.

Answer (score 0):

(Post instead of comment due to rep, sorry)
First of, you can make a graph with just HTML & CSS. However, this is not recommended. With JS and npm it is easier, as you can use things like Chart.js.

That is the technology you were looking for. On how to actually use it, I'd recommend you the [official documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/).